# PHPExcel outputting zeros as blank cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm building a WordPress plugin using PHPExcel to export reports of student attendance.  So far, I'm able to successfully take the array of student data (including attendance) and convert and download it as a spreadsheet.  Unfortunately, there's an odd bug: when a student has attended zero events, that cell on the spreadsheet is blank instead of showing a zero.  I'd prefer it come out with an actual zero, but I can't find a way to do that.  Here's my script:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL);
ini_set( 'include_path', ini_get( 'include_path' ).';../Classes/' );

include 'PHPExcel.php';
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex( 0 );
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator( $user );
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy( $user );
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle( $title );
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject( $title );
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription( $title );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $data, null, 'A1' );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

$columns = array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' );

foreach ( $columns as $column ) {

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);

} // End $columns foreach

$file_name = str_replace( ' ', '_', $title);

if ( $_POST['type'] == 'spreadsheet' ) {

header( 'Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel' ); 
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '.xls"' );

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007( $objPHPExcel );
$objWriter->save( 'php://output' );

}
```

$data contains the array of student info, which is structured like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => First Name
        [1] => Last Name
        [2] => BU ID
        [3] => Barcode
        [4] => Major
        [5] => Class
        [6] => Seminars
        [7] => Showcases
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [first_name] => Seth
        [last_name] => Abel
        [buid] => B00385307
        [barcode] => 100324707
        [student_major] => CMM
        [class] => MBU2100
        [seminar] => 0
        [showcase] => 1
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [first_name] => Zachary
        [last_name] => Abend
        [buid] => B00373103
        [barcode] => 100291996
        [student_major] => MBU
        [class] => MBU2100
        [seminar] => 0
        [showcase] => 1
    )
.
.
.
)
```

As you can see is the example data, the those students have each attended 1 showcase, but zero seminars.  When this spreadsheet is downloaded and opened in Excel, the 1 shows up fine, but the seminar cells are blank.  Since I'm using the fromArray() function to populate the spreadsheet, is there something I should do to make those zeros appear properly?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think you are a victim of loosely-typed comparisons here - you have specified `null` as your second parameter to `fromArray()`, which represents the `Value in source array that stands for blank cell`. Since `null == 0` this means that zero will result in a blank cell unless you set the fourth argument to `true`.

Try changing:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $data, null, 'A1' );
```

...to...

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $data, null, 'A1', true );
```

Comment: Thanks Dave!  I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't hunt it down.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: I couldn't find this anywhere on the site, but a 1-second search on Google came up with this question as the 1st result. I'm not sure if that's more of a good thing for StackOverflow or a bad thing for PHPExcel's documentation.

Comment: @DaveRandom this doesn't work for me. I am using `phpexcel` 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2023, you must use PhpSpreadSheets, which is the evolution of Phpexcel.

For avoid show blank instead of showing a zero, you could indicate text format for the specific cols:

in this case I indicate that columns From B to D have FORMAT_TEXT  `getStyle('B:D')`

```php
// you should include this use.
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B:D')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maatwebsite/excel (also known as Laravel Excel) 3.x, you just have to implement the `WithStrictNullComparison` interface in your export model.

```
class MyExcelExportModel implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnFormatting, WithMapping, WithStyles, WithStrictNullComparison
{
     [...]
}
```